# What does $f \in H^\infty$ mean?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, notation

I am reading [this research paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0087893#page-1) about polynomials with non-negative coefficients. Can some one tell what does the notation $f \in H^\infty$ mean so that I can research about this function class?

Comment: To me it looks like a Hardy space, that is, that of bounded holomorphic functions on the unit disk with the supremmum norm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$H^\infty$ is the class of bounded holomorphic functions on the open unit disc (or sometimes the upper half-plane).

It is one of the [Hardy spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space).